# how to resolve failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, response, fetch-api

[image: data is not showing in response section]

POSTING API

`export const resendInvitation = async (userName) => { await API.post( 'delta-api',`user-mgmt/users/${userName}/resendInvitation`, {} ); };`

`const handleResendInvitation = async () => { await resendInvitation(userName) .then((response) => { setOpen(false); }) .catch((e) => { setOpenNotification(true); setNotificationMessage(e.response.data.message); }); };`

help me to get the response data

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with the backend server configurations. Setting the environment variable as Development resolved the issue.

I hope it helps at least with figuring out some things.